# Programmatically Reset Persistent Store file in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

We know the message

The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store

We also know the solution. Just delete the apps, reset.

Can we do that programatically?

The core data only store cache result anyway.

That way once the apps are online I do not have to worry about updating core data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `NSFileManager` to delete the data store file on disk.

Comment: How do we check whether the data model is still "consistent"

Comment: Try creating the persistent store coordinator and then calling `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`. If it returns `nil`, something went wrong and you can delete the file and call the method again.